# Hibernate Spatial Create Geometry object

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle-spatial, hibernate-spatial

I am developing an location app with oracle spatial in Java. I am using hibernate 4.0 spatial for orm layer. I am new in spatial and i couldn't find best practise for hibernate spatial. My database model following;

```
CREATE TABLE SYSTEM.POI  (
    POI_ID          INTEGER,
    SERVICE_ID      INTEGER,
    POI_NAME        VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR2(1023 CHAR),
    CATEGORY        VARCHAR2(127 CHAR),
    ADDRESS         VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
    MOBILE_PHONE    VARCHAR2(15 CHAR),
    FIXED_PHONE     VARCHAR2(15 CHAR),
    BUSINESS_HOURS  VARCHAR2(1023 CHAR),
    SHAPE           SDO_GEOMETRY  
)
```

insert statement is following;

```
INSERT INTO SYSTEM.POI (SERVICE_ID, POI_NAME, DESCRIPTION, CATEGORY, ADDRESS, MOBILE_PHONE, FIXED_PHONE, BUSINESS_HOURS, SHAPE)
VALUES(
        '1320',
        'PO-Kral Petrol Ürünleri San ve Tic. Ltd. şti.',
        'Camilerimiz',
        'CAMI',
        'İSLİCE MAHALLESİ DERE SOKAK NO:5',
        '2762151093',
        '5552552343',
        'Hafta içi  09:00 - 17:00, haftasonu 09:00 - 13:00 açık',
        SDO_GEOMETRY(
            2001, 
            3785,
            SDO_POINT_TYPE(28.90762, 41.1521, NULL),
            NULL,
            NULL
        )
      );
```

entity model is following i'm sharing just sdo_geometry object;

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

...

    @Column(name="SHAPE")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType")
    private Geometry shape;

    public Geometry getShape() {
      return shape;
    }

    public void setShape(Geometry shape) {
      this.shape = shape;
    }
```

How can i fill this spahe object with dynamic parameters. For example;

```
  SDO_GEOMETRY(
                2001,  --> sdo_gtype
                3785,  --> sdo_srid
                SDO_POINT_TYPE(28.90762, 41.1521, NULL),  --> sdo_point
                NULL,  --> sdo_elem_info
                NULL   --> sdo_ordinates
            )
```

How to pass sdo_gtype,sdo_srid,sdo_point_type parameters to geometry object dynamically?

Comment: Not an answer, but just something I want to point out: your SRID is set to 3785. This the global spherical mercator projection (as used by Google). But your coordinates look like WGS84 long/lat. The proper SRID for that is 4326.

Comment: yes you re right my fail 3785. I changed it 8307 for long/lat wgs84

Answer (score 12):

You can create as shown below.

```
com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point p = new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(12.34343, 12.232424));
System.out.println(p);
```

In the `GeonmetryFactory` constructor you can pass precision model, srid and CoordinateReferenceSystem.

However there is spatial wrapper around `JTS` called `geolatte`, which is shipped with Hibernate Spatial(automatically downloads jars in maven). You can create `Point` using `Geolatte` as shown below.

```
        org.geolatte.geom.Point<G2D> point = Geometries.mkPoint(new G2D(12.34343, 12.232424), CoordinateReferenceSystems.WGS84);
        System.out.println(point);
```

There are utility class to tranform from `JTS` to `Geolatte` and vice-versa. And attaching output of the program also.

```
        org.geolatte.geom.Point<G2D> point = Geometries.mkPoint(new G2D(12.34343, 12.232424), CoordinateReferenceSystems.WGS84);
        System.out.println(point);
        com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point p = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326).createPoint(new Coordinate(12.34343, 12.232424));
        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println(JTS.to(point));
        System.out.println(JTS.from(p));
```

**Output:**

```
SRID=4326;POINT(12.34343 12.232424)
POINT (12.34343 12.232424)
POINT (12.34343 12.232424)
SRID=4326;POINT(12.34343 12.232424)
```

**UPDATE**

Projection you are looking for is supported by `Geolatte`, [here](http://System.out.println(CrsRegistry.getProjectedCoordinateReferenceSystemForEPSG(3785).getName());%20%09%09org.geolatte.geom.Point%3CC2D%3E%20point1%20=%20Geometries.mkPoint(new%20C2D(12.34343,%2012.232424),%20CrsRegistry.getProjectedCoordinateReferenceSystemForEPSG(3785));%20%09%09System.out.println(point1);) are SRID supported by `Geolatte`, Since you are using Project CS, you need to use C2D(Cartesian 2D)

Here is code example to create

```
        System.out.println(CrsRegistry.getProjectedCoordinateReferenceSystemForEPSG(3785).getName());
        org.geolatte.geom.Point<C2D> point1 = Geometries.mkPoint(new C2D(12.34343, 12.232424), CrsRegistry.getProjectedCoordinateReferenceSystemForEPSG(3785));
        System.out.println(point1);
```

output:

```
Popular Visualisation CRS / Mercator (deprecated)
SRID=3785;POINT(12.34343 12.232424)
```

Comment: Thank for you answer i tried but your srid and mine is difference. i am using 3785 srid. I couldnt find this srid in CoordinateReferenceSystems is there this srid?